# Backbone.js route and scroll position

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm creating a really basic website with a list of projects of which you can click and then view more details about that project.

The problem I'm having is that when you scroll down the list of projects, then go to the project detail view, it doesn't reset the scroll position to the top. So you are at the bottom of the new page, which is annoying.

I'm quite new to Backbone.js – has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 1):

i found the same problem on my projects (with backbone). The solution is used is that :

```
App.Router.on("route", function(data){
  $(document).scrollTop(0);
});
```

So, everytime routing is called, before render the new view, the document page return automatic on top. I hope can help.
Remember you need "bind" this on 1 time, not each view ;)

EDIT:
if the routing is not "triggered" when you create the new page, apply this line

```
$(document).scrollTop(0);
```

on the correct event :)

EDIT2 :
Watching your code (final part)

```
var projects = new App.Views.Projects();
var project = new App.Views.Project();

var theRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '': 'home',
            ':id': 'project'
        },

        home: function() {
          projects.render();
        },
        project: function(id) {
          project.render({id: id});
        }
    });

    var router = new theRouter();

    router.on('route', function() {
        // MAKE SURE ROUTING BIND IS CALLED
        console.log("Hey, im routing !!!");
        $(document).scrollTop(0);
    });

    Backbone.history.start();
```

Try this

Comment: I originally had `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` on my view render method. So it would render and then scroll back to the top causing a flicker. Will try it on the route event, thank you :)

Comment: Still seems to flicker :(

Comment: Seems strange, you can add some picture and some piece of code? maybe i can help better.

Comment: Yes the 'route' event is firing

Comment: On my mac i have safari and chrome, and if i test the command ($(document).scrollTop(0);) on firebug console work fine. Test if is ok also on your browser, maybe add that line directly after view.render(etc) .

Comment: I've tried to show the flicker in a video: http://youtu.be/poWzOf6x5lo?t=36s - do you see it? Or maybe it's because I haven't specified the width and height of the big image. Will test that.

Comment: yes, i think is for this reason. After the render command, the real html render is on the hands of browser, and maybe cause that :(
But is very fast, not annoing.